# How to output a Double as a String to x decimal places with no trailing zeroes

Tags: c#, string, double

I need to output various numbers with various decimal places (DP) as strings with 6 DP unless there is trailing zeroes. For example:

0.123456789 = 0.123456

0.1234 = 0.1234

0.0 = 0

I'm trying to use
"input.ToString("*insert number format code here*")"
but I either get the correct amount of DP but all the trailing zeroes (0.000000) or it doesn't work at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `TrimEnd('0')` an option?  You can also use patterns such as `0.######` instead of standard format strings.

Comment: Please give us a code example that demonstrates the issue you're having. If you look through the documentation, there are a number of ways to achieve what you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=net-5.0 one of which would be input.ToString("N2")

Comment: YES! 0.###### is exactly what i needed! Thank you. That's been driving me nuts :)

Comment: You could also use `"g6"` as the format specifier, for up to 6 dps with truncated trailing zeroes. (But note that for really huge numbers, "g" uses exponential format.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal solution here is that suggested above using `.ToString("0.######")` to format the input :)